# What could have possibly gone wrong with Google Calendar v3 app in a .NET 5 Core API that it would suddenly stop working after a year+ of uptime?

Tags: c#, google-calendar-api, google-workspace, google-api-dotnet-client, service-accounts

I've first verified that the failure occurs directly as a result of executing the following ListRequest by stopping any resulting processing by the app after the request is executed:

```
EventsResource.ListRequest(builder.GetCalendarService(), "user@domain.com") { Key = "API_KEY", TimeMin = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-3), TimeMax = DateTime.Now.AddDays(21), ShowDeleted = false, SingleEvents = true, OrderBy = EventsResource.ListRequest.OrderByEnum.StartTime };
```

All other Requests have stopped working also.  Building the GoogleCredential and CalendarService is executing without error unless it doesn't execute until the actual Request execution:

```
string[] Scopes = {
                CalendarService.Scope.Calendar,
                CalendarService.Scope.CalendarEvents,
                CalendarService.Scope.CalendarEventsReadonly};

            FileStream stream = new FileStream(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "auth\\apiinfofile.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            
GoogleCredential credential;
            credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream).CreateScoped(Scopes).CreateWithUser("user@appname.iam.gserviceaccount.com");
   
            CalendarService service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer { HttpClientInitializer = credential, ApplicationName = "appname" });
```

Was there a recent change to the API that I'm unaware of?

I was using ver 1.49 of the Google API packages and tried updating to ver 1.55 since that's the only thing that's changed as far as I can tell but no luck.

Is there anything that will expire or something along those lines that need to be updated?

Comment: Please define stops working.   What exactly is the issue with your code.  You appear to be using a service account have you checked if there is anything wrong with your google workspace account?

Comment: There is no way for us to answer this question because it contains almost no detail. You need to do some basic debugging to figure out that detail. By doing that debugging you will almost certainly discover the issue anyway.